# Why can't I see the names of people who liked a post

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Why can't I see who liked a Facebook post?  I get the number of likes, but no names.

Comment: Hi and welcome!  Which operating system, version, Web browser, and version are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.